# Matching vector network to slope raster dataset in ArcGIS Desktop Advanced

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, slope

I am trying to calculate the average slope of a rivers network. Each part of the network is broken up into individually numbered segments. I have a high resolution slope raster and thought I could match this to the river network.

Is there an appropriate way to achieve this using ArcGIS Desktop?

[image: River network and slope raster]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/) (GME) for this type of analysis.  Keep in mind there are both ArcGIS and R dependencies for GME.  Specifically, use [isectlinerst (Intersect Lines With Raster)](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/isectlinerst.htm).  The tool creates a statistical or frequency summary of raster data along a line (polyline) based on a raster layer.  For continuous rasters, the length weighted mean is calculated in addition to min/max and beginning/end raster values.

I created some test data to illustrate how this works:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. Convert DEM into a flow accumulation grid
2. Threshold this grid to create a raster version of you river network
3. Use this extracted stream network to mask your slope grid when converting the slope grid into a point layer
4. Do spatial join of points to closest polyline or the near tool so you get a relationship of 1 polyline near *x* number of points.
5. Average the slope values using the polyline ID as a group by field.

Another method is to simply extract the end points of each polyline, use these to query the DEM then do the difference over distance.

As your image shows the main problem is that the vector network does not precisely follow the channel in your grid.

Have a look at the help file as this explains the steps for extracting a network from a flow accumulation grid.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd thanks a lot for your suggestion, it worked really well and I appreciate the help!